# Syntax error - Python re.search (character class, caret)

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Scraping pages using BeautifulSoup; trying to filter out links that end in "...html#comments"

Code follows:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://voices.washingtonpost.com/thefix/morning-fix/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)).findAll('a')
links_to_follow = []
for i in soup:
        if i.has_key('href') and \
    re.search(base_url, i['href']) and \
    len(i['href']) > len(base_url) and \
    re.search(r'[^(comments)]', i['href']):
        print(i['href'])
```

Python 3.2, Windows 7 64-bit.

The above script retains a link ending in "#comments"

I tried `re.search([^comments], i['href'])`, `re.search([^(comments)], i['href'])` and `re.search([^'comments'], i['href'])` -- all threw syntax errors.

New to Python, so apologies for banality.

I'm guessing either 
    (a) I don't understand enough about the 'r' prefix to use it correctly or 
    (b) in response to [^(foo)] re.search returns not the set of lines that exclude 'foo', but the set of lines comprised of more than 'foo' alone. e.g., I keep my ...#comments link because ...texttexttext.html#comments precedes it or
    (c) Python interprets "#" as a comment ending the line re.search is supposed to match.

I think I'm wrong on (b).

Sorry, know this is simple. Thanks,

Zack

Comment: You should include the exact text of the errors/tracebacks you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^(comments)]
```

means "one character that is neither a `(` nor a `c`, an `o`, an `m`, an `e`, an `n`, a `t`, an `s` or a `)`". Probably not what you intended.

If your goal is to have a regex that only matches if the provided string does not end in `#comments`, then I would use

```
... and not re.search("#comments$", i['href'])
```

or even better (why use a regex at all if it's that simple?):

```
... and not i['href'].endswith("#comments")
```

As for your other questions:

The `r'...'` notation allows you to write "raw strings", meaning that backslashes don't need to be escaped:

- `r'\b'` means "backslash + b" (which will be interpreted by the regex engine as "word boundary"
- `'\b'` means "backspace character"
- etc.

`#` has no special meaning in a regex unless you use the `(?x)` or `re.VERBOSE` option. In that case, it does indeed start a comment in a multiline regex.

Comment: Had to step away and just now getting back - thanks both for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Regex might not be the best solution here:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://voices.washingtonpost.com/thefix/morning-fix/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)).findAll('a')
links_to_follow = []
for i in soup:
    href = i.get('href')
    if href is None:
        continue
    if not href.startswith(base_url):
        continue
    if href.endswith('#comments'):
        print href
```